# "Where he is" vs "Where is he"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following.

> "You know where he is"

and

> "You know where is he"

Comment: One is English, the other one isn't. Sorry but I have to close.

Comment: There was a question about exactly this topic the other day -- embedded vs non-embedded questions and subject-verb inversion.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 Okay, that is interesting, but you didn't mention which one is English and which one is not?

Answer (score 3):

> Where is he? Do you know where he is?
>
> Yes, I know where he is.

The natural subject-predicate order is inverted in special questions (those beginning with an interrogative pronoun such as what, where, etc), but not in object clauses.

By object clause I mean a clause that substitutes a single-word object. For example:

> I know [him]. I know [this song]. I know [where he is].